# running parameterized bigquery via cell magic in jupyter notebook

Tags: google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

I've got a problem with pydatalab: I just installed it and normal querying and charting via cell magic works fine.

The wiki for pydatalab says, it's possible to add [chart controls](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/wiki/Charting-and-Chart-Controls#chart-controls). But that wiki uses some old `%%sql` syntax instead of the new `%%bq query` one which don't work anymore.

Weird thing is, the following works fine:

```
%%bq execute -q tmp_result_na
parameters:
- name: name
  type: STRING
  value: 'value'
```

Thank you (in advance) very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found **[this open issue](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/issues/374)**. It's not implemented right now....